# Numbers from set of digits with limited repetition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have 3 digits: 1,2 and 3. I want to create numbers with length of 9 digits but I am **only allowed** to use each digit **exactly 3 times**.

For example: 111222333

I can find the number of all possible combinations by using the multinomial coefficient: $$\binom{9}{3,3,3} = \frac{9!}{3!^3} = 1680$$

What I would like to know is how to iterate over those numbers in order.

For example number 111222333 is the first number. On the other hand 333222111 is the last (greatest).

Is there a way/method so I can get which is the number after 111222333? Is there a way to somehow correlate/correspond the number 111222333 with 1, number 333222111 with 1680 and all the between numbers? So for instance, can I answer which is number 18 in this special order of numbers?

Sorry I am new to this, I presume that there are already lots of theories and mathematics to explain all these but I would really appreciate a simple explanation and some pointers to where I can study more!

Comment: You are looking to *rank* and *unrank* the lexicographically ordered permutations of the multiset. [Here's a paper](http://www.ijetae.com/files/Volume4Issue1/IJETAE_0114_76.pdf) that outlines an algorithm to do this. There are other ways to do the same, Google the terms "rank" "unrank" "multiset" "permutation", e.g.

Comment: Don't you mean you want to create numbers with a length of $9$ digits?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yea sorry. Fixed